# help modifying jquery to create a table from a csv

Tags: jquery

I am using this http://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/
to generate a table in a webpage from a csv. It works great, but I need to add an image url in the csv and have the code show the actual image instead of just the url string. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a sample few lines of your CSV? It should be as simple as changing the `.text()` assignment to a `.html()` and adding the image markup.

Comment: thanks. the csv just has /images/name.jpg address in the images field.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to do it without modifying jquery.csvToTable.js

To do it, you can edit line 131 to test if the item is an image URL and append the image HTML with the item in the `src` attribute

Comment: awesome info, I don't have that basic js knowledge. where can I look to start?

Comment: closer? the lines in question:

$.each(items, function(itemCount, item) {
tableHTML += '<td class="' + options.tdClass + '">' + item + '</td>';
});

I need to insert an "if" that looks for an image url and replaces with imag tag. Not sure where that goes exactly.
I know I want to show the image like this:
$('<img></img>') .attr('src', 'images/' + image_url) But do i insert it in the same string above or in a seperate statement? Excuse my ignorance, but I am trying to get this!